# How to add a hide text (Hide Spoilers) button in your Microsoft Word 2010 document

Tags: pdf, word-2010

I am curretently trying to type a document about a game, a sort of walkthrough if you wil based on other sources I wil refer to.

The point is there are sometimes 'spoiler material' that spoil the story. While I can add a warning in the document, this document contains spoilers.

Now I know you can hide text and I know how to it, by going to you text settings and then set the text to hidden.

But considering this document will be "Interactable" by converting it to a pdf file for upload, I want to make "Spoiler Warning click here to reveal" or something like that. Kind of when you use "Spoiler Tags" in a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create that kind of interactivity in a PDF by creating a button and adding the spoiler text to the tooltip using Acrobat or another PDF editing tool. However, there is no way to author such interaction using Word and converting to PDF.